# Android: take the content from a thread

Tags: android, multithreading

I wrote this code to take the content from a json parser. The first time, i had the "listInfo = jp.info();" and "listContent = jp.content();" in the onCreate() method but with this way, the app had a delay at the loading! So, i added the runJP() method for more speed but now i can't take the content of listInfo and listContent! What must i do?

```
private ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> listInfo = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();
private ArrayList<HashMap<String, HashMap<Integer, String>>> listContent = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, HashMap<Integer, String>>>();
public JSONParser jp = new JSONParser();

public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.map);

    mapView = (MapView) findViewById(R.id.mapview);
    mapView.setBuiltInZoomControls(true);

    runJP();

    mapLocationOverlay = new MapLocationOverlay(this);
    mapView.getOverlays().add(mapLocationOverlay);
    mapView.invalidate();
}

private void runJP() {
    new Thread(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            listInfo = jp.info();
            listContent = jp.content();
        }
    }).start();
}
```

Comment: What do you mean you can't take the content of listInfo and listContent? Why not? Is your app crashing? Is the variable null? Can you post the exception if it is crashing? Have you stepped through your code to see exactly what is happening in runJP?

Comment: no the app isn't crashing! with the jsonparser i took coords and title form a jsonarray. with the runJP() method i can't take the data from listInfo and listContent. If the listInfo and listContent are in the onCreate() method (without thread), then i take the data!

Answer (score 0):

Check out [AsyncTask](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html). It was made for this exact purpose.

This allows you to run code in another thread and then update the UI thread when you're done.

[This article explains how to use it](http://www.screaming-penguin.com/node/7746).

Answer (score 0):

Use a [Handler](https://web.archive.org/web/20200810154212/http://www.tutorialforandroid.com/2009/01/using-handler-in-android.html) to send the parsed data from the thread to the Activity. At the end of your Runnable you can create a Message, set the Message's object to be an array with the 2 objects and then you'll receive that in your Handler.

Answer (score 0):

You could also use `.runOnUiThread(runnable)` to update UI on UI thread:

```
private void runJP() {
    new Thread(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            listInfo = jp.info();
            listContent = jp.content();
            // added
            YourActivity.this.runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                public void run() {
                    // here you can safely update the UI
                }
            });
        }
    }).start();
}
```